# How to point to a Spring resource using Maven parent pom/child poms directory structure?

Tags: spring, maven, classpath

I have a Maven parent pom, and 2 child projects.  I am using Spring, and can't get the classpath to point from child_project_2 to a resource in child_project_1.

```
parent
  child_1
    - src
      - main
        - java
          - com
            - company
              - package1
                  - app1.java
      - resources
          -config.xml

  child_2
    - src
      - main
        - java
          - com
            - company
              - package2
                  - app2.java
        - resources
```

When I run app1.java, I load the config.xml file using:

ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("src/main/resources/config.xml");

However when I run app2.java, and need to load in the config.xml, I can't seem to get the classpath correct.  Using this Maven directory structure, how can all my sub-projects that use Spring point to the same config.xml file that lives at child_1/src/main/resources/config.xml?

I've tried the absolute path on my local machine.  I've tried the relative path from child_2 up to parent and back down to config.xml, and the relative path from child_2/src/main/resources back up to the parent and down to config.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

src/main/resources is only where the source resources are kept. When the JAR is built, the files in that directory are copied into the JAR alongside where src/main/java files are built.

If both JARs for child_1 and child_2 projects are on your classpath, your code should look like:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT- based on your comments, additionally: project 1 needs to be a dependency of project 2 (or create a common module and make each depend on it).

EDIT again - to remove src/main/resources from the urls.

The argument to the constructor you're using is a resource. Try

```
ApplicationContext ctx = 
    new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:config.xml");
```

or

```
ApplicationContext ctx = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
```

I always use the latter, and it's probably what you intend here.

with maven, things in src/main/resources  will be put on the classpath.

for more on what Spring resources are, even though it's largely irrelevant now: 
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-loader-with-getresource-example/

BTW - you should include the sources of spring in your IDE and browse the source, that's what I did, makes it easy to figure out what's going on, you can just run through the debugger.

If you use IDEA and Maven, this is automatically available in the IDE, just choose 'download sources' from the maven window. (or browse to the class in IDEA, and click 'dwonload sources' when it opens the class file )

Comment: So given my diagram, when I am running app1.java, both of the above lines you gave work fine.  However, when running from app2.java, I can't get the classpath to find the config.xml that lives in child_1/src/main/resources.  
So the point of my question is that I don't want to have to make a copy of config.xml and stuff it in every child's src/main/resources folder.  Rather, I want to have app[n].java be able to load the config.xml from child_1/src/main/resources/config.xml.  However I can't get the classpath correct.

Comment: if you want it to be available in both apps, create a 3rd module called common, and make app1 and app2 depend on common (by adding it as a dependency to their poms). or you can make app2 depend on app1. but you can't make app1 and app2 depend on each other, that's a circular dependency (chicken and egg problem - which gets built first?)

Comment: your comment about using a resource fixed it. From child_2:
res = new FileSystemResource("child_1/src/main/resources/config.xml");
ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(res);

Comment: that's not good though, it's tying you to a specific file location - once you package your app as a jar it stops working. classloader resources are much more portable... so you've solved your problem at build time... but once you package it.. you'll run into a problem again

Comment: See my answer. You don't need "src/main/resources" when you identify it on the classpath (in fact, that will cause it to not work).

Comment: @JonathanW it does work on my local machine, but haven't tried to package and run it from a jar yet.  But I do understand what you are saying, and will make sure that the jar sticks it with the rest of the files so I can point to it as you mentioned.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of Maven entirely. I'd suggest reading up on Maven lifecycles before continuing down the path you're on.